# notification system with django, nodejs and socket.io

Tags: django, node.js, notifications, socket.io

I really need your guidance. What I want to create is something like a notification system. Please consider this scenario. There are three users (*userA*, *userB* and *userC*). Now, *userB* and *userC* are friends with *userA*. Suppose, *userA* posts a new blog. How do I notify *userA's* friends (*userB* and *userC*) that there's a new event or blog, like twitter, facebook etc? And suppose *userB* comments on *userA's* blog, how do I notify it to *userA* that a new comment has been commented on his blog like facebook. And if *userA* comments back, how do I notify *userB* of that event. And lastly if *userC* also comments on that blog, how do I notify both *userA* and *userB* about that event? I have alrealy made the friend system and used the signals to notify the users related to that objects. But, I don't want them to refresh always for that. How do I this with **nodejs**. I am bit familiar with **socket.io**. But I am confused, about how to notify particular users about this that, when I publish or emit, it will be sent to all the users in the site. I am really confused. I will really really really appreciate if you could guide me how to this. Thank you!

Comment: found a solution yet ?

Comment: @FrozenFlame Not yet. Do you have the solution?

Comment: i still notify all users , i haven't designed a friends specific notification system, sorry to disapoint you , but i don't think anyone will be willing to share social design secrets with you(just a guess, i wish i'm wrong)

Comment: @FrozenFlame Yes, it is sad ( and I don't think you are wrong! ). But I have however touched nodejs and socket.io with django for messaging purpose, and its really great. But not yet implemented. Will answer here if I find the solution.